# Recursive mpi spawns (spawn from spawn)

Tags: c, recursion, openmpi

The problem is quite simple: a manager spawns X workers. Each worker spawns 2 more workers if a condition is met. Everything works fine as long as the workers don't spawn anymore (so condition not met, or if only the first "original" worker spawns; hangs for the other workers).

Manager code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int myrank, numworkers, tag = 3, sum = 0, K = 1;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Comm workercomm;

numworkers = atoi(argv[1]);

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
MPI_Comm_spawn("Project_child",
        MPI_ARGV_NULL, numworkers, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,
        &workercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

for (int i = 0; i < numworkers; i++) { //sends 1,2,3... to workers
    K=i+1;
    MPI_Send(&K, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, workercomm);
}

for (int i = 0; i < numworkers; i++) { //receives an int from worker
    MPI_Recv(&K, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, workercomm, &status);
    sum += K;
}
printf("%d \n", sum);

MPI_Comm_free(&workercomm);
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Worker code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int K, myrank, tag = 3;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Comm parentcomm;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parentcomm);

MPI_Recv(&K, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, parentcomm, &status); //recv K
printf("child %d: k=%d\n", myrank, K);
K++;
if (K<5) { // && myrank==0) {
    MPI_Comm childParentComm;
    MPI_Comm_spawn("Project_child",
            MPI_ARGV_NULL, 2, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,
            &childParentComm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
    //problem might be here?^

    //sends the K to first worker_child
    MPI_Send(&K, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, childParentComm);

    //!!!!!!! IT HANGS HERE if worker != 0

    K++;
    //sends K+1 to second worker_child
    MPI_Send(&K, 1, MPI_INT, 1, tag, childParentComm);

    int K1, K2;
    MPI_Recv(&K1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, childParentComm, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&K2, 1, MPI_INT, 1, tag, childParentComm, &status);
    K = K1 + K2;
    MPI_Comm_free(&childParentComm);
}
MPI_Send(&K, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, parentcomm);
MPI_Comm_free(&parentcomm);
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

OK, I changed the code to simplify it.

Tested the code, problem is the same: worker0 spawns additional children (even his child0 spawns additional children), the others don't and they hang at the second send. So if the condition would be (if (K<5) && myrank==0), it would work, but that's not what I need.

Comment: Can you reduce this to something simpler? If the problem is that your spawned processes can't spawn new processes, try creating a reproducible example that demonstrates that without all the extra math. It's a lot easier to help you if you have a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WesleyBland - done, I hope it's fine now

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. I was able to run this code without a problem. I changed the name of the binary, but so the spawn command had `./child`. Otherwise everything was the same.

Comment: Wow, really? Maybe it has something to do with my virtual machine. I installed openmpi 1.4 a long time ago. Tried to install a newer version but it's such a pain in the back, I can't seem to get it done properly.
I will try to make a clean VM tomorrow.

If I put a printf in the worker BEFORE the MPI_Send to the second worker_child (where I wrote the comment "//sends K+1 to second worker_child")  it prints. If I put it AFTER, it doesn't print, because it just hangs there.

Glad to know my code is actually fine.